# SQL Server: Return Special Count Column based on two Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to grab the count of "Code" contained in each "ID".  Consider this table I would like to have:

```
╔════════╦════════╦══════╗
║   ID   ║  Code  ║ Count║
╠════════╬════════╬══════╣
║    111 ║ abcd   ║ 2    ║
║    111 ║ abcdes ║ 2    ║
║    222 ║ dddd   ║ 1    ║
║    333 ║ ddww1  ║ 3    ║
║    333 ║ ddww2  ║ 3    ║
║    333 ║ ddww3  ║ 3    ║
║    444 ║ abcde1 ║ 2    ║
║    444 ║ abcde2 ║ 2    ║
╚════════╩════════╩══════╝
```

As you can see, it returns the number of codes in each ID.

I'm thinking something like this... but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT COUNT(CODE) AS CODE_COUNT FROM TABLE1 a, TABLE1 b WHERE a.ID=b.ID;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce6dc/6)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1( ID INT,Code VARCHAR(20))
GO
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES

(111,'abcd'),
(111,'abcdes'),
(222,'dddd'),
(333,'ddww1'),
(333,'ddww2'),
(333,'ddww3'),
(444,'abcde1'),
(444,'abcde2')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A.ID
      ,A.Code 
      ,Sub.CODE_COUNT
FROM TABLE1 A
 INNER JOIN (
             SELECT ID , COUNT(*)  AS CODE_COUNT 
             FROM TABLE1
             GROUP BY ID) Sub
ON A.ID = Sub.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce6dc/6/0)**:

```
|  ID |   CODE | CODE_COUNT |
|-----|--------|------------|
| 111 |   abcd |          2 |
| 111 | abcdes |          2 |
| 222 |   dddd |          1 |
| 333 |  ddww1 |          3 |
| 333 |  ddww2 |          3 |
| 333 |  ddww3 |          3 |
| 444 | abcde1 |          2 |
| 444 | abcde2 |          2 |
```